# open different folder in inbox using PHP imap_open

Tags: php

I am using this PHP Code to open a POP3 mailbox:

```
$hostname = '{mail.domain.com/pop3:110/notls}INBOX';
$username = 'email@domain.com';
$password = '***';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
```

i am using the above code to open a POP3 mailbox

i tried using

```
$hostname = '{mail.domain.com/pop3:110/notls}INBOX';
```

to open a folder inside the inbox but i got the error:

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {mail.domain.com/pop3:110/notls}INBOX.Support in /home/integra/public_html/autocheck/support_emails.php on line 31
```

how can i open different under my Inbox folder?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.php.net/imap_open) you need use this format:

```
"{" remote_system_name [":" port] [flags] "}" [mailbox_name]
```

So
`{mail.domain.com/pop3:110/notls}INBOX`

should probably be
`{mail.domain.com:110/pop3/notls}INBOX`

Also make sure you can actually connect to the server on port 110, for example on a Linux/UNIX machine you can test this with:

```
$ telnet example.com 110
```

If you see `Escape character is '^]'.`, you're connected.

Comment: so how do i open a folder inside the inbox?

Comment: I think you want imap_reopen()